Odd behavior of Netcat
I'm trying to debug connection issues within my home network. To do that, I'm using Netcat to figure out if two machines can talk to each other over UDP on a specific port.
On the reveiver's end, I use
sudo nc -ul <port>

and on the sender's end
echo "message" | nc -u <reveiver-hostname> <port>

The following happens

The receiver shows "message"
The sender never completes the nc command, just hanging
I quit the send command (Ctrl-C)
I send another message
The receiver does not receive this message
The sender does not hang and quits immediately
I quit the listen command on the receiver and start it again
The loop repeats

In summary, per "nc listen" I can transfer exactly one message. The send commands does not exit if the message is received.
My expectations would be that the send command does its thing and then exits. It's UDP so there is no point in doing anything but pump out a few packets and be done. This does not seem to be the case. On the receiver side I would expect it to receive an arbitrary amount of packets and show them on the console, not matter from where or when they arrive.
It seems that either there's a weird bug or I fundamentally misunderstand the way this is supposed to work. Can somebody help me out?

While UDP is connectionless at protocol level, a UDP socket can still be "connected to" – which generates no messages but still has the same effect of binding the socket to a specific remote address:port at the OS level.
Once connect() has been called, calling recv() will only deliver datagrams from the specified sender to the program, and vice versa, the program can also call send() on that socket without specifying the recipient (as opposed to using recvfrom() / sendto() on an unconnected socket).
Your implementation of nc calls connect() upon receiving the first packet, to "lock onto" that particular flow, while the sending side will create a new socket and therefore choose a different source port number every time you restart it.
To achieve what you want, you'll probably need socat udp-recvfrom:[...] (not udp-recv), although you can try nc -u -p 12345 <dst> <port> to force each sender process to bind to the same local (source) port every time.
